# When i trying to copy folder from amazon ec2 to s3 .I got an error

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run this command 
`aws s3 sync images/ s3://mybucket/myfolder`
I get an error

> A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

How to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your region must be supporting the new AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 and your AWS CLI version must be old. Upgrade your AWS CLI version and that error will go.

Comment: How can i update CLI

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/04/how-to-update-the-aws-cli-tools-linux/